# How do I create custom data format like these?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqldatatypes

I'm currently using Oracle SQL Developer 11g. Can anybody tell me how do I create the data format for my columns like these (and then put them in CREATE TABLE command):

1. The COACH's ID type which has the format like: `COACH[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` for example: `COACH0107` **(got it)**
2. The DOB (Day Of Birth) DATE type which has the format like: DD-MM-YYYY *(How can I create a constraint to specify that the input DATE must be DD-MM-YYYY and not YYYY-MM-DD or anything else ?)*

Comment: You should use Database triggers to do this kind of validation in oracle.

Comment: If you want to display a date in a specific format, format it using `to_char()`. There is no way you can create your own `date` datatype that formats differently. Formatting is **always** done by the client application. To validate the `coach` column use a check constraint

Comment: You should not use a trigger for this. You can use a `varchar2` field with a regex check constraint. This looks like homework so I'll leave that as a hint rather than a full answer *8-)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for your advice ! But how do i format an input date by using to_char() ? I've never used this function before !

Comment: You don't format the *input* - you format the **output**. To insert/update a date value use a valid date *literal* by either using an ANSI date literal or the `to_date()` function with a proper format mask.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks.. but can you tell me with a little more details ? What I want now is if the others want to insert a row to this table, they can go like INSERT INTO (table_name) VALUES ('COACH0001','14-11-1970'); for example ? So what should I now when I create this table ? At the moment my code is like
CREATE TABLE (table_name)
(
ID VARCHAR(9),
DOB DATE,
CONSTRAINT hlv_id_format
  CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(ID,'HLV\d\d\d\d'))
);

Comment: Again: **a date column does *not* have a format**. To insert/update values you can use *any **valid** date literal* - regardless of the format: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0b036/1 more details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ

Comment: ahhhh ! Then that's the one who write INSERT command to specify the DATE format, not the table creater, right ?

Answer (score 2):

> "so I think I should create my own DATE type"

No, you really shouldn't.  Oracle stores dates in its own special format.  We can then display those values in any format we choose.  It is simply a question of applying the required mask in the client (displaying) environment.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210).

As for enforcing the format of the Coach ID, like most experienced database developers I dislike such keys.  They are always more trouble than they're worth.  However, some customers insist on them.

The best way to enforce data formats is with a check constraint.  Use [`TRANSLATE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions216.htm#SQLRF51933) to convert any digit into a standard number...

```
 alter table your_table
      add constraint coach_id_format check
          ( translate(coach_id, '0987654321', '9999999999') = 'COACH9999')
```

This will throw an exception whenever somebody attempts to persist an ID which doesn't consist of 'COACH' followed by four digits.   For a more complicated mask you could use [a regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm#SQLRF06302) but there's really no need here.

Comment: thanks ! About the ID's format I've handled it. But about the date type, how can I specify the input DOB date type is DD-MM-YYYY and not YYYY-MM-DD or anything else ?

Comment: @rainman_TS7: The *input* is handled in your application, not in Oracle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: my code is CONSTRAINT dob_format
  CHECK (TO_CHAR(DOB,'dd-mm-yyyy')), and Oracle displays an error @@

Comment: @rainman_TS7 checking the format of a date using a check constraint does not make *any* sense because (as APC already said): **dates do *not* have a format**. Oracle will make sure you cannot store an invalid date value in a date column.